# How do i remove a item in Dictionary if value is TRUE

Tags: python, loops

So this is the dictonary with student id numbers. i want too remove the student if "passed":True.

```
test_grades = {
    9210114413 : {"grade": 55, "passed": True},
    9010054514 : {"grade": 22, "passed": False},
    8504129392 : {"grade": 60, "passed": True},
    9201134555 : {"grade": 15, "passed": False},
}
```

I've tried for-loops if-statments with different methods and still can't get it right. Help would be appreciated. Im a beginner so bear with me. Thanks

Tried this also

```
x = {}
for d in test_grades:
    for grade,point,p,tof in d:
        if tof == True:
            x.pop(tof)

print(x)


#Try 2
x = {}
for d in test_grades:
    if test_grades[d]["passed"] == True:
        del x[d]

print(x)
```

Comment: Do it the other way around.  Create an empty dictionary, and copy the elements you want to KEEP.

Comment: You shouldn't modify a dictionary or list while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 2):

It's always better to build a new structure with the elements you want to keep.

```
x = {}
for d in test_grades:
    if test_grades[d]["passed"] != True:
        x[d] = test_grades[d]

print(x)
```

Or:

```
x = {}
for key,val in test_grades.items():
    if not val['passed']:
        x[key] = val
```

Or, one-liner:

```
x = { k:v for k,v in test_grades.items() if not v['passed'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright. You were on the right track with your second approach but you were deleting entries from the *x* dictionary rather than the test_grades dictionary which you want to modify. Also you cannot modify the dictionary that you are iterating over because it will result in a runtime error `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. You can modify your second approach as follows:

```
test_grades = {
    9210114413: {"grade": 55, "passed": True},
    9010054514: {"grade": 22, "passed": False},
    8504129392: {"grade": 60, "passed": True},
    9201134555: {"grade": 15, "passed": False},
}

x = {}
for student_id, data in test_grades.items():
    if not data["passed"]:  # Check if "passed" is False
        x[student_id] = data  # Add the entry to the new dictionary
```